# running multiple instances of .exe

Tags: windows, multiple-instances

I have an executable (e.g. `test.exe`).

How can I run that same executable multiple times in parallel? The easiest way is to open several `cmd` windows and run `test.exe` from there, but that's probably not the fastest, or even easiest, way do it.

Comment: You can build a batch file loop and call your exe multiple times

Comment: How about using a batch script that contains several lines of "test.exe"?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new batch file (e.g. multirun.bat) with the following contents.

```
@echo off 
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %1) do start %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Usage:

```
multirun.bat times command 
e.g. multirun 3 calc
```

Tested on Windows 7 x64. If you don't want to see new console windows, use "start /b" on the script.

Answer (score 1):

Make an appropriate "shortcut" for the executable, and then clicking on the shortcut's icon
N times will launch N instances, unless the app has been written to prevent that.